# how can I validate jsx template and labeling score?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to implement `if , elif, else` in jsx template to achieve the following data scoring,and labeling based on the scoring but I am unsure how.

```
Low – 0.0 – 3.9
Medium – 4.0 – 6.9
High – 7.0 – 10.0
```

I Have a div with the following code

```
{feeds.map(post => 

    <button className="search-buttons detail-button">{post.cvss}</button>
)
```

Comment: What is `feeds`?

Comment: it's a server-side variable where it render the api data to my component

Answer (score 1):

Within **JSX** directly, we cannot use `if/else` or loops like (`for`,`while`). What we can use however is **ternary operator**.

**Syntax DEMO:** `{isLoggedIn ? 'currently' : 'not'}`

Use this resource from React Official Docs to get you sorted with this.

[Conditional Rendering within JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

You can however use `if/else` within a function that returns JSX into you code. (That case is also covered in the docs linked)

Comment: what about for 3 labels? how would it be?

Comment: Dear ana osuna. You can do nested of terniary operator. But I actually didn't understood what you are specifically trying to achieve. Do one thing. Create you object structure codesandbox and share the link with me. So that we can actually see what is going on and how to resolve it